# Running project downloaded from stackblitz

Tags: angular9, stackblitz

I have downloaded a running project from stackblitz (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-form-builder) of dynamic form builder.
I am using angular 9, and unable to run it on local machine after installing dependencies(using npm install).

it is saying error TS2339: Property 'isHovering' does not exist on type 'FileComponent'. But on stackblitz it is working fine. any help will be appreciated.

Comment: any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Great question. I had the exact same problem.
I ran **ng update @angular/cli @angular/core** and everything then worked accordingly.

Hope this helps. Cheers.

M